# How to set the Animation-Style from code?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, core-animation

I am replacing a view inside a navigation controller with the setViewControllers-method.
But i dont like the look of the transition. How can i set the animation-style when using the following code ?

```
UIViewController *newVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SuccessScreen"];
    NSMutableArray *viewControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[self navigationController] viewControllers]];
    [viewControllers removeLastObject];
    [viewControllers addObject:newVC];
    [[self navigationController] setViewControllers:viewControllers animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
CATransition *yourAnimation=...;
[self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:yourAnimation forKey:nil]
[[self navigationController] setViewControllers:viewControllers animated:NO];
```